# Fusion Chart - overlapping data labels on trend and bar charts - old version 3.0.3

Tags: charts, overlap, label, fusioncharts

This is the issue:

[image]

and I have read that you can change the position of data labels in Fusion Charts 3.2 but we are using 3.0.3 version and can not upgrade (several reasons).

So, I am just asking, has anyone faced this issue several years ago and common with work around?

Comment: Are you sure the version you're using is v1.2.3? How are you finding out the version number?

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari Yes, I am a completely sure. We are using this version for several years and have not updated it. I have try to use some property - "placeValuesInside='0'" in order to force the Bar chart values to show outside the bars, but nothing changed.

Comment: Try using `valuePosition` with either `ABOVE` or `BELOW`. I'm not sure if this attribute is supported in the older version.

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari I am afraid, the "valuePosition" attribute is supported since FusionCharts v3.2. That's why I said the version that we are using.

Comment: If your chart look the way your screenshot looks (the column 3D and lie with shadow), then you are definitely using minimum of FusionCharts version 3. Possibly v3.1 or earlier, but probably not 3.2. By 1.2.3 you might be referring to the string "Version: 1.2.3" which is in the header of your FusionCharts.js. This is the version of this JavaScript file. To know your chart's version, you need to enable chart's debug mode. I suggest you can  upgrade now.

Comment: @sudimail you are complete right - thanks I will correct this in my question - the version is 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeValuesInside='0' will work only when the columns' roof come very near to the canvas top margin.

Anyway, I have used other option in order to fix the issue: valuePadding='0'

The problem was that there is a default padding between value text and the end of column.